# Virtual emulator IsolateStorage in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

For debugging purpose, I would like to check what file has been saved while executing and I want to read that file.

For example I use this code:

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream stream1 = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SomeTextFile.txt", FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage);
```

How can I check out or access that `SomeTextFile.txt` from my PC? Or access to that file somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new [Windows Phone 7.1 SDK tools](http://aka.ms/wp7sdk), there is an Isolated Storage explorer tool that will allow you to peer into (and modify) your application's Isolated Storage. More info can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: it's all commandline, so don't look for some app to help you do it. It works, but it is all done through the commandline...

Answer (score 2):

This might be worth checking out also [Windows Phone 7 Isolated Storage Explorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/) as it has a desktop client and also integrates into visual studio.